# JQuery Ajax function error when indeed there is a success

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

My code calls the error function, even when it hits the Action url as it is supposed to. Here is the Jquery ajax code:

```
function ContactDialog(action, controller) {    

var url = '/' + action + '/' + controller;

$("#ContactDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: true,
    hide: "fade",
    show: "bounce",
    height: $(window).height() / 2,
    width: $(window).width() / 2,
    title: "Send an email",
    buttons: [{
        text: "Send", click: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,                                     
                data: $("form").serialize(),
                context: this,
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json", //xml, json, script and html
                success: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    sendConfirmMessage('msgSent');                        
                },
                error: function () {
                    sendConfirmMessage('msgNotSent');
                }
            });
        },
    }, {
        text: "Cancel", click: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }]
});
```

And here is the html/razor code:

```
<div style="margin-top: 10px; visibility: hidden;" id="contactLink">
    <h3><a href="#" onclick="ContactDialog('SendEmail', 'SendMail')">Contact me</a></h3>
</div>

<div id="ContactDialog" style="display: none;">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm(null, null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "UpdaterDiv" }, new { id = "contactForm" }))
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.subject)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.subject, new { @class = "AboutControls" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.subject)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.from)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.from, new { @class = "AboutControls" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.from)
        <br />
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.body)
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.body, new { @class = "AboutControls AboutControlTxtArea" })
        <br />
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.body)
        <hr />
        <br /><br />
    }
</div>

<div style="display: none;" title="Info" id="msgSent">
    <p>Thank you, your message has been sent </p>
</div>
<div style="display: none;" title="Info" id="msgNotSent">
    <p>There was an error sending you message, please try again </p>
</div>
```

Here is the Action method that is hit as success, and it does call this method, but it returns error, as if it doesn't call thisAction method. Any idea what might be wrong?

```
       public PartialViewResult SendMail(EmailModel model)
    {
        string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SMTPHOST");
        int port = Convert.ToInt16(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("SMTPPORT"));
        string receiver = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TOADDRESS");
        string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("PASSWORD");

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(host, port);
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(receiver, password);
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;

        MailMessage mailMsg = null;            

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                mailMsg = new MailMessage(model.from, receiver, model.subject, model.body);
                smtp.Send(mailMsg);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SendErrorMail("m@mail.net", "...", "Exception", ex.ToString());
        }

        return PartialView("_About");
    }
```

Comment: I guess I was wrong on we have a success. So what is a success in terms of JQuery Ajax? Debugging my sever side code, it returns the view as it should, and it behave as expected, no exception thrown

Comment: This was the solution, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that might help.... and folks will correct me if I'm wrong! It seems that the success and error functions are missing some parameters. Ideally we should at least pass `data`as parameter.

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,                                     
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            context: this,
            contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json", //xml, json, script and html
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Here is the the data - ", data);
                $(this).dialog("close");
                sendConfirmMessage('msgSent');                        
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("Oops, didn't work - ", data);
                sendConfirmMessage('msgNotSent');
            }
        });
```

I would also log out some info to see the progress. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax options specify `dataType: "json",`, but the method you are calling returns a partial view (html). Change the option to

```
dataType: "html",
```

Side note: Use the `UrlHelper` to constuct your urls

```
var url = '@Ul.Action(action, controller)';
```